# using AutoMapper with constructors and methods

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map from NewPatient (DTO) to Patient (domain model with encapsulation)

```
public class NewPatient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public Patient(string name)
    {
       Name = name;
    }
    public Patient AddEmailAddress(string email)
    {
       EmailAddresses.Add(email);
       return this;
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<string> EmailAddresses { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

the reason I've created Patient like this is so I can create the Patient, something like

```
  var patient = 
        new Patient("Dave")
            .AddEmailAddresses("dave@example.com");
```

I've created my Mappings as follows:

```
 CreateMap<NewPatient, Patient>()
                .ConstructUsing(dest => new Patient(dest.Name));
```

is it possible for me to add the ability to use the method **AddEmailAddresses** with AutoMapper?

I've tried
CreateMap<NewPatient, Patient>()
.ConstructUsing(dest => new Patient(dest.Name))

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.EmailAddresses, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest)=> {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.Email))
                    return dest.AddEmailAddresses(src.Email);
                return null;
            }));
```

Looking at the class, the email gets added to the EmailAddresses list, and everything else maps well, however, I receive an error from AutoMapper

```
 NewPatient -> Entities.Patient Destination Member: EmailAddresses
```

Comment: Are you looking for AfterMap action? https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Construction.html

Comment: @funatparties that's it thank you. I had read the documentation but I must have missed it. Many thanks